How to specify path for temporary (large) files
I am using Ghidra on a Linux computer. My ghidra project is stored in a folder which is automatically synchronised with a cloud storage.
Now I noticed that in the cloud storage a large number of temporary, deleted files with large size have accumulated, tmp*.ps and   db.1.gbf, db.2.gbf ..., each about 200 MB large.
HERE i read that these files contain the current project state (using "save").
Maybe it is a stupid question, but is there a way to specify a different temporary files path, so that they do not pollute the cloud storage, possibly keeping the feature of continuous backup to cloud storage? The temporary ps do not look like postscript files but seem to contain the project state.
There is also a large number of smaller files like changeA.grf or snapshotA.grf  (also ...B...).
Perhaps there is only a solution when ghidra splits the project state into smaller files, where many remain unchanged, so that the amount of data to sync with cloud storage is smaller.
